# Basic Git Workflow Assistance

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and am trying to understand the basic workflow when working with other developers.

We have a remote `development` branch that the developers push to.

1. Fresh pull of `development` remote branch to get new updates...

   ```
   git pull origin development
   ```
2. Do a bunch of work in my `development` local branch
3. Add and commit new work that I just did

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m "completed x"
   ```
4. Push changes to the `development` remote branch

   ```
   git push origin development
   ```

I'm wondering if there is a much more optimized and better way of doing this? Note that I'm only working with one or two other developers.

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by a "more optimized" and "better" way to implement your workflow?

Comment: I just want to say I'm sorry for my rather rude earlier responses.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no more "optimal" way to do this (I'm guessing you mean fewest steps?). What you've outlined above is the minimum number of required steps necessary for a typical git workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about working with a group and having some kind of development-release-deploy process, here's a good overview of two common workflows: [Git Workflows For Successful Deployment](http://bocoup.com/weblog/git-workflows-for-successful-deployment).

I use the "git flow" pattern with my current team.  The article discusses some of the pro's and con's.

Answer (score 0):

Working on your own feature branch and later merging the same with the main development branch is in my opinion a far better way to work. If you have main development branch, you can create a branch on top of it and push your changes.

For example, if I have a branch "master", and If I am working on a new feature Feature_A

I would do something like this.

```
git checkout -b feature_a
```

(The above command is given while I am on master branch)

I will make my changes and push the "feature_a" branch.

```
git push origin feature_a
```

Now when my feature is completed, my colleague managing the "master" branch would merge my branch into it.

```
git merge feature_a
```

(The above command is given while he is on master branch)

Even if you are working with a couple of other developers, it is always better to work on your own branches and merge the same after testing a feature completely. This will keep your releases more clean and organized.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# fetch everything from remote but don't modify anything local
git fetch

# checkout the development branch;
# this will automatically track the remote branch
git checkout development

# do some work and commit it
git commit -m 'whatever'

# fetch changes and rebase the development branch against the remote changes
git pull --rebase

# push changes
# (all branches by default but can be changed to just current branch)
git push

# continue to pull --rebase, commit, and push
```

There are some variations on this but you should consider rebasing against remote commits before pushing your local changes to remote. More mature OSS projects will generally insist on this and it is good practice. You can make rebasing the default pull behavior (normally it merges).